# Is it possible to load a single column of a matrix that is already saved in a .mat file?

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have been given a large .mat file which looks like this:

```
whos('-file','grips.mat')
  Name       Size               Bytes  Class     Attributes

  grip1      1x1              1662198  struct              
  grip2      1x1              2032758  struct              
  grip3      1x1              1660278  struct              
  grip4      1x1              1650678  struct              
  grip5      1x1              1607478  struct              
  grip6      1x1             63353718  struct
```

Each grip has several recorded muscle signals (EMG) of a person gripping, from several sensors.  I want to load only one of these sensor signals for one of these grips.  I want to do the following but it doesn't work:

```
EMG_signal = load('grips', 'grip6.data(1,:)')
```

The closest I can get is this:

```
EMG_signal = load('grips', 'grip6');
EMG_signal = EMG_signal.grip6.data(1,:);
```

However this involved loading several times as much data as I needed, then discarding it.  Is there simple short-cut?

This would also apply for an object stored in a .mat file - surely I wouldn't have to load the whole object just to get the value of one of its variables (properties).

Many thanks.

Comment: separate them to multiple files?

Comment: Even the [matfile object interface](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/matfile.html) won't work to index into the fields of a structure (unfortunately) - unless you can restructure the `.mat` files, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: If you have to do this a lot of times for the same datafile, you can always save the data again to new file, eg: `save('EMG_grip_6_1.mat','EMG_signal')`

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question. It looks like it depends on which version of Matlab you're running. Mathworks added the [matfile function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/matfile.html) as of R2011b.

But unfortunately, your specific problem still can't be solved as you have structures and not straight up matrices stored. If 'grip6' were a matrix, you could access just the sub-matrix like this:

```
matObj = matfile('grips.mat')
EMG_signal = matObj.grip6(1,:)
```

But as the documentation says,

> matfile does not support indexing into:
>
> - Fields of structs

For further reading on how Matlab doesn't support the loading of parts of matrices or arrays from mat files, see this [matlab central thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/9208).